# SSO between gitlab and azure AD doesnt work

Tags: azure, gitlab, entra-id, oauth

```
### OmniAuth Settings
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/integration/omniauth.html
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['azure_oauth2']
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_sync_email_from_provider'] = 'saml'
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_sync_profile_from_provider'] = ['azure_oauth2']
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_sync_profile_attributes'] = ['azure_oauth2']
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_sign_in_with_provider'] = 'azure_oauth2'
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_ldap_user'] = false
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_saml_user'] = false
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_external_providers'] = ['azure_oauth2']
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
    {
      "name" => "azure_oauth2",
      "args" => {
        "client_id" => "ee72xxxx-xxx",
        "client_secret" => "G9dxxx",
        "tenant_id" => "0c17xxxx-xxx",
      }
    }
  ]
```

At the minute I don't get the option to enable this as an OAuth option in Admin > Settings > Sign-in restrictions, on the login page there isn't a login with button and when I use the azure 'myapps' portal pressing the link takes me to the GitLab login page instead of logging me in, and there is no option to connect my profile in the integrations bit of my profile.

Thanks for reading my mini essay, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of GitLab are you running?

First off, are you running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`   and   `gitlab-ctl restart`   after making any changes to `gitlab.rb`?

c.f.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703246/cant-enable-google-login-omniauth-on-gitlab-ce#34110727

Do you have LDAP enabled at all? My understanding is that Azure still uses the LDAP users and you will want this line `# gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_ldap_user'] = false` uncommented and set to `true`.

Check out this *working* configuration: [Gitlab Omniauth to Azure ID (SSO) questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/923413/gitlab-omniauth-to-azure-id-sso-questions)

Also, don't you want this line to be enabled: `# gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_sign_in_with_provider'] = 'azure_oauth2'`

Comment: Been on holiday didn't see the post, sorry.

Comment: No worries! It looks like GitLab has updated these settings and option a bit in 11.2.x

Comment: We literally just upgraded from 10.3 to the latest - that'll probably be where the issue started. Thanks!

Comment: Right! Best of luck